# error C2059: syntax error : '.'

Tags: c++

I am trying to get this function to work, but I keep getting

> error C2059: syntax error : '.'

on the lines of the two declare() function bodies where I call is_declared, and I can't figure it out.  I know it has to do with is_declared, but I am having trouble.

---

```
class Variable {    
public: 
    std::string name;
    double value;
    char type;      
    Variable(std::string n, double v) :name(n), value(v), type('v') { }
    Variable(std::string n, double v, char a) :name(n), value(v), type('c') { }
};

class Symbol_table {
public:
    Symbol_table();
    double get(std::string s);
    void set(std::string s, double d);
    bool is_declared(std::string s);
    double declare(std::string var, double val);
    double declare(std::string var, double val, char c);
private:
    std::vector<Variable> var_table;
};
Symbol_table::Symbol_table() {}
double Symbol_table::get(std::string s)     
{
for (int i = 0; i<var_table.size(); ++i)
    if (var_table[i].name == s) return var_table[i].value;
error("get: undefined name ",s);
}
void Symbol_table::set(std::string s, double d) 
{
for (int i = 0; i<=var_table.size(); ++i)
    if (var_table[i].name == s) {
        if (var_table[i].type == 'c') error("set_value: Cannot change a constant's value");
        var_table[i].value = d;
        return;
    }
error("set: undefined name ",s);
}
double Symbol_table::declare(std::string var, double val)
{//error here
    if (Symbol_table.is_declared(var)) error(var," declared twice");
    var_table.push_back(Variable(var,val));
    return val;
}
double Symbol_table::declare(std::string vari, double valu, char c)
{//error here
    if (Symbol_table.is_declared(vari)) error(vari," declared twice");
    var_table.push_back(Variable(vari,valu,c));
    return valu;
}
bool Symbol_table::is_declared(std::string s)   
{
for (int i = 0; i<var_table.size(); ++i)
    if (var_table[i].name == s) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `std::find()` and other functions from `<algorithm>` are your friends; they let you write many common kinds of loops in simpler, more readable fashion. Also, using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` here would simplify things a lot, and give you better performance.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `Symbol_table.is_declared` is not valid C++ in that context. Most likely you meant to write

```
if (this->is_declared(var)) error(var," declared twice");
```

You can also omit the `this->` if you prefer, that's a matter of style.

Comment: why do you need the this? surely you just call the member functions for the class direct if (is_declared(var)) error(var," declared twice"); or am I missing something?

Comment: I am newer to C++ and doing an exercise in a book, so I am not sure what the this does, but I tried it without the this and it worked. So when you are using a member function in another member function you do not need to specify the member?  Or am i not understanding what I did wrong?

Comment: this is an implicit pointer to your class instance accessible by non static members, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dddwwd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx it also shows that in your code it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Fuddlebutts: You do not need to qualify class members on your class or its bases from inside a method, so `this->` is optional. However if you don't use `this->` then you cannot tell just by looking at the call site if `is_optional` is a method or a free function.